# Подключение видео через стандартный тег Video

Tags: html, css, видео, mime

Пытаюсь подключить на сайт видео с сервера. При помощи конструкции ниже. Естественно задаю content-type video. Но все равно видео не читает. Не может прочесть ни один формат, будь то webm или mp4. Выдает ошибку "видео в поддерживаемом формате и типе MIME не найдено". Загвоздка в том что если я запускаю сайт через index.php в оффлайне, то все работает хорошо, а если с сервера, то нет. Как это можно исправить? Думал что нужно что то исправлять в MIME Type но понятия не имею где он находится и как его стоит менять

```
    <video controls loop>
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    </video>
```

Comment: А что происходит, когда вы пытаетесь открыть видео по ссылке на видео `site.ru/video.webm`? Возможны ошибки в url или неверное перенаправление ссылки. Ну и, конечно, нужно добавить mp4 формат, он самый поддерживаемый.

Comment: @Crantisz , ничего и не происходит, перебрасывает на главную страницу, но с адресом site.ru/video.webm

Comment: Значит у вас `.htaccess` настроен неверно. Он обрабатывает ссылку на видео переадресуя ее на главную страницу.

Comment: Немного пошаманив, добился того что при переходе на site.ru/video.webm начало выдавать сам видеоролик. Открыв .htaccess попытался подключить форматы, но все равно ничего.

Ниже по ссылке содержимое файла .htaccess
https://ideone.com/K70Iji